# Why would I change my realm layout?

Tags: genshin-impact

I recently unlocked the Silken Courtyard realm layout.

[image: Realm Layout Preview]

However I cannot see why I would change to a new layout. None of my furnishings go with me, so I would have to rebuild everything. I tried before, as you can see on Cool Isle.

I don't understand why you would switch layout?

- I'd have to rebuild everything
- I would lose my realm currency generation
- I would lose progress on my companions friendship level

Is switching realm layout purely just for aesthetic purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes, it's aesthetic purposes. The idea is that you can have multiple realms to decorate in different ways, and the ability switch between them at will. If you don't like building stuff in the tea pot, then switching layout confers no real benefit.

There aren't any downsides to it, either.

- Your furnishings carry over between realms. If you have only 1 table, you can place that same table in all 5 of your realm layouts
- For currency generation, only your highest-energy realm layout is considered, even if it's not the active one
- You cannot lose Companionship EXP

Comment: Ah, so I could share furniture to create a few different companion sets, that's interesting