# How do I settle a companion in my Serenitea Pot?

Tags: genshin-impact

After finding out I can use [extra Realm Layouts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404781/why-would-i-change-my-realm-layout) without disadvantages I have setup one with some of the companion sets in to earn the primogems from the reward.

However after adding the sets and putting the companions in, I get mixed messages when inviting companions to the set.

[image: Diona, Amber and Razor]

[image: Ningguan and Keqing]

How can I collect the gifts I already have? Is this because these companions are in my other Realm Layout?

How long do I have to wait for the companion to become settled so I can talk to them and collect the reward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the wording is quite confusing, but you should be able to understand each label just by observing how things work.

You can place a companion wherever you want in the pot.

When a companion is **anywhere** in the pot and the corresponding set is available:

- if you already collected the gift you will see the message "**Already settled in**" and the character will stay where you placed them
- if you never collected the gift and no one else is waiting at the set, the character will move there and wait for you. In this case you see the message "**Gift event has yet to be completed**". After you collect the gift they will return to their place.
- if you never collected the gift but someone else is already waiting at the set, you get a message "**Please collect the gifts you currently have**". They will try to move to the set as soon as it becomes free.

When multiple characters are available for a set, only one will go there and the other will wait for the set to "free-up". I don't know how the priority here works, I assume it is either character ID or join date.

When the set is free you can also invite a character there to listen to the dialogue again.

NOTE: If you place a set and then place the character nearby manually things may get confusing because it may look like TWO characters are there but that is not the case (ex: built a Cottage Kitchen and put Xianling there, then add Mona somewhere else , Mona will move there too if you already got Xiangling gift since the set is "free").